# How to differentiate $a(t-1)+bt+(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dB_s}{1-s}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

someone can help me to differentiate 
$$a(t-1)+bt+(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{dB_s}{1-s}?$$

I've tried but I really don't know how to do with the last part..

Thank you somuch for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $$X_t=a(t-1)+bt+(1-t)Y_t,\qquad Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm dB_s}{1-s},$$
then $$\mathrm dY_t=\frac{dB_t}{1-t},\qquad \mathrm dX_t=a\mathrm dt+b\mathrm dt+(1-t)\mathrm dY_t-Y_t\mathrm dt,$$ hence $$\mathrm dX_t=\mathrm dB_t+\left(a+b-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm dB_s}{1-s}\right)\mathrm dt,$$ and $$\mathrm d\langle X\rangle_t=\mathrm dt.$$ **Edit:** In full generality, if $Z_t=U_tV_t$, Itô's formula reads $$\mathrm dZ_t=U_t\mathrm dV_t+V_t\mathrm dU_t+\mathrm d\langle U,V\rangle_t.$$
Using this for $U_t=1-t$ and $V_t=Y_t$, one gets $\mathrm d\langle U,V\rangle_t=0$ because the quadratic variation of $U$ is zero, hence one is left with the sum $$U_t\mathrm dV_t+V_t\mathrm dU_t=(1-t)\mathrm dY_t-Y_t\mathrm dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the Ito formula in the form:

$$
d\left[\left(\alpha(t) +\int_0^t a_s dB_s\right) 
      \left(\beta(t) + \int_0^t b_s dB_s\right)\right] 
\\= \left(\alpha(t)+\int_0^t a_s dB_s\right)\left(d\beta(t) +  b_t dB_t\right)
     + \left( d\alpha(t) + a_tdB_t \right)\left(\beta(t) + \int_0^t b_s dB_s\right) +  a_sb_s ds
$$
where $\alpha,\beta:\Bbb R^+\to \Bbb R$.

Comment: but if I use this formula: $dY_{t}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_{t}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} dt$: I obtain: $$a+b-\int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{dB_{s}}{1-s}+dB_{t}$$ is it right?

Comment: and all the derivate with respect to $B_{t}$ are equal to 0?

Comment: I fail to understand the hint. Maybe the upvoter can explain?

Comment: @Did: is that better this way?

Comment: No. How is this alpha-beta product corresponding to the situation the OP asks about?

Comment: with $b = 0$, $\beta(t) = 1-t$ and $\alpha(t) = 0, a_s = 1/(1-s)$.

Comment: This seems to overcomplicate the setting for no visible gain. Anyway, where are the $\alpha'(t)$ and $\beta'(t)$ terms (assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differentiable, which is also missing)? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did: this is something good to know when you start using the Ito formula. OP could need this extension very soon. I made the final edit.

Comment: Now the formula is correct. But I could not give any reason why this restricted formula should be remembered instead of the general one (to which one has to come back, anyway, to determine that your first version was faulty and that the modified version is correct).